# Table view not updating when called from another View Controller using NotificationCenter

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, notificationcenter

I have a table view in one view controller. I want to update the table view from another VC. I'm doing this using NotificationCenter like this:

In the table view VC:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateTableView), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateTableView"), object: nil)
}

@objc func updateTableView() {
    print("in func")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.listTV.reloadData()
    }
}
```

In the opened VC:

```
func reloadTV() {
       NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateTableView"), object: nil)
}
```

The `print` works, but the table view doesn't reload. I can only see it changing if I dismiss the VC with the table view and open it again.

I've followed the suggestions of other answers which is to use `DispatchQueue`, but that didn't make a difference. What am I missing?

Many thanks!

Comment: Is `reloadData` getting called? If so, it probably has something to do with updating the datasource.

Comment: is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` getting called after printing `"in fun"`?

Comment: @sinio I'm facing the same problem. Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider doing this by protocol and delegate instead of notifications... 
This is how I do it.

Comment: Must work. Then u maybe screwed something up with the array? U have to show us more code...

Answer (score 0):

When you call tableView.reloadData(). It has no effect if the tableView is hidden (isHidden == true). I believe the behavior is also the same when the tableView is effectively hidden by another ViewController (so effectively hidden).

Solution: A suggestion is to reload the tableView when the view is shown again. Few ways to do that. 
one is in viewDidAppear (depends on how you transitioned between ViewControllers), 
or

you can keep a reference to the tableView and after you dismiss the second ViewController (in which you were sending the notification) you provide the callback to reload the tableView. Roughly like the snippet, with self being the **secondViewController** you transitioned to. Dismiss that view

```
  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

or you can still use your notification and setup a flag and when the viewDidAppear, you then reloadData() inside viewDidAppear. However for this to work, you need to ensure that viewDidAppear is always called when the view is shown again (this will depend on how you transitioned between views).Simply override that method and print to verify.

There are other ways but the bottom line is tableView.reloadData() will be ignored if it is called when the tableView is not visible on the screen. My guess is it's an optimization made by Apple (no need to reload if no table is showing) or maybe a bug. I think they'll say it's a feature

Comment: I tried this - I even added a delay to reloading the table view to make sure it was finished loading in - but it still doesn't update :/

Comment: Is the first view controller the one with the tableView triggering a segue to the second view controller where you want to do the update?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest instead of using `NotificationCenter`, to instead set a `Bool`, `tableViewNeedsUpdate`, and check for the value of that `Bool` when the view with the `UITableView` is presented, and the `UITableView` is visible and able to accept `reloadData()` calls. After the reload is complete, set the variable back to false.